# Can't split a string by a parenthesis on Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, split, parentheses

For example the following code:

```
$test_str = 'foo(bar';
@arr = split('(', $test_str);
```

causes the 500 error

Why?

Comment: You should check what error the program produces. Your web server should log those. But short answer is that `(` is a not a valid regex pattern, which is what `split` expects for its first argument.

Comment: @ikegami thank you. It works with `split(/\(/, $test_str)`

Comment: I guess I was too slow.

Comment: @simbabque yeah, just a few seconds)

Answer (score 7):

As [ikegami says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63575242/cant-split-a-string-by-a-round-bracket-on-perl/63575370#comment112421228_63575242), [`split`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) expects a pattern as its first argument. A string will just be converted into a pattern. Because an open parenthesis `(` has a special meaning, this will error. You need to escape it.

```
my @arr = split /\(/, $str;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to `perldoc -f split`, the first argument to the `split()` function is a regular expression `/PATTERN/`.  So if you were to write this:

```
split('some text', $string)
```

it would be equivalent to:

```
split( m/some text/, $string )
```

And if `some text` contains characters that are special in regular expressions, then they will treated as such.  So your line:

```
@arr = split('(', $test_str);
```

will be treated as:

```
@arr = split( m/(/, $test_str );
```

This is likely not what you want, as `m/(/` is an invalid (you could say incomplete) regular expression.  To match on a literal `(`, you need to escape it with a back-slash, so use this instead:

```
@arr = split( m/\(/, $test_str );
```

By now  you've noticed that Perl tries to be helpful by converting your first argument from the string `'('` to the regular expression pattern `m/(/`.  Although you can pass in a string as the first argument, I don't recommend it -- use `m/PATTERN/` instead.

The reason for my recommendation is because:

1. A pattern makes it clear that the first argument is a regular expression pattern, and not just any old string.
2. According to `perldoc -f split`, there is a special case where you *can* pass in a string as the first argument:

> As a special case, specifying a PATTERN of space (' ') will
> split on white space just as "split" with no arguments does.
> Thus, "split(' ')" can be used to emulate awk's default
> behavior, whereas "split(/ /)" will give you as many null
> initial fields as there are leading spaces.  A "split" on
> "/\s+/" is like a "split(' ')" except that any leading
> whitespace produces a null first field.  A "split" with no
> arguments really does a "split(' ', $_)" internally.

It's good not to confuse the two.  So use `' '` as the first argument to `split()` when you want to use the special case of splitting on whitespace, and use `m/PATTERN/` as the first argument for every other case.